# Remove gmail warning email not verified when sending mail with PHP

Tags: php, smtp

Good morning,
I want to remove the gmail warning 'gmail couln't verify that ...@... sent this message' when I send email with php.

I know it is because I use the email function php  that don't have authentification  so I try PHPMailer and PHP pear but the page turn and turn until the infinite and nothing is happened.
My host is 1&1. 
I try with gmail instead smtp and account instead of 1&1 but same result.

```
<?php
    // Pear Mail Library
    require_once "Mail.php";
    $from = '<***@motelavigna.co>'; //change this to your email address
    $to = '<***@gmail.com>'; // change to address
    $subject = 'Insert subject here'; // subject of mail
    $body = "Hello world! this is the content of the email"; //content of mail

    $headers = array(
        'From' => $from,
        'To' => $to,
        'Subject' => $subject
    );

    $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', array(
            'host' => 'auth.smtp.1and1.fr',
            'port' => '465',
            'auth' => true,
            'username' => '***@***.co', //co is not an error
            'password' => '***' // your password
        ));

    // Send the mail
    $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);
?>
```

thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I came across this issue recently too and realised the problem is not from the PHP script, as I first thought, but from not having an SPF record for the domain name.

An SPF record identifies which mail servers are permitted to send emails from a particular domain name. If the domain doesn't have an SPF record then Gmail can't verify that the email came from the right place.

Coincidentally I'm also with 1&1, so see [here for how to set up SPF records for 1&1](https://www.ionos.co.uk/help/domains/configuring-mail-servers-and-other-related-records/using-an-spf-record-to-prevent-spam/). The value you need to use is:

```
v=spf1 include:_spf.perfora.net include:_spf.kundenserver.de -all
```

You can also check if the email passed the SPF test by clicking the arrow at the top of the email in Gmail, and pressing 'Show original'.

[image]

Comment: thanks it's working, with simple emai but not with PEAR mail but it is sufficient for me.